# Why do the plot lines disappear in my Win32 application?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to write a light Win32 program (OS is Windows XP SP 1) which should draw a 2D plot from a data set stored in a .csv file. I'm using Code::Blocks IDE with a MS Visual C++ Express 2008 compiler. Therefore, I'm also using SDK as a source of Windows headers and libraries.

Here's the code:

#### main.cpp

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include "daneWykres.h"

static TCHAR szWindowClass[] = _T("win32app");

static TCHAR szTitle[] = _T("Win32 Guided Tour Application");

POINT logicalUnitSize;
RECT ClientRect;

HINSTANCE hInst;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,
            _T("Call to RegisterClassEx failed!"),
            _T("Win32 Guided Tour"),
            0);

        return 1;
    }

    hInst = hInstance;

    logicalUnitSize.x = 560;
    logicalUnitSize.y = 560;

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(
        szWindowClass,
        szTitle,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        100, 100,
        logicalUnitSize.x, logicalUnitSize.y,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
    );

    if (!hWnd)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,
            _T("Call to CreateWindow failed!"),
            _T("Win32 Guided Tour"),
            0);

        return 1;
    }

    GetClientRect(hWnd,&ClientRect);

    ShowWindow(hWnd,
        nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    daneWykres* rysik = new daneWykres;
    rysik->sczytaj(); // method putting data from CSV into a static array dane[][]
    int iloscPunktow = rysik->getRozmiar(); // a getter for the array's size (number of points)
    double minX = rysik->najmniejsza(0); // the lowest X coordinate
    double minY = rysik->najmniejsza(1); // the lowest Y coordinate
    double maxX = rysik->najwieksza(0); // the highest X coordinate
    double maxY = rysik->najwieksza(1); // the highest Y coordinate

    int lgXokna = 30; // top left corner X coordinate of the border rectangle
    int lgYokna = 30; // top left corner Y coordinate of the border rectangle
    int pdXokna = ClientRect.right - lgXokna; // bottom right corner X coordinate of the border rectangle
    int pdYokna = ClientRect.bottom - lgYokna; // bottom right corner Y coordinate of the border rectangle

    POINT punkt;
    punkt.x = 0;
    punkt.y = 0;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        HPEN hPenOld;
        HPEN hSolidPen;
        HPEN hBluePen;
        COLORREF qLineColor;
        qLineColor = RGB(0,0,0);
        hSolidPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, qLineColor);
        qLineColor = RGB(0,0,255);
        hBluePen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 2, qLineColor);
        hPenOld = (HPEN)SelectObject(hdc, hSolidPen);

    // the border rectangle
        Rectangle(ps.hdc, lgXokna, lgYokna, pdXokna, pdYokna);

        hPenOld = (HPEN)SelectObject(hdc, hBluePen);

    // draws text every time a daneWykres constructor is called
        if (rysik->getFlaga() == true) DrawText(ps.hdc, TEXT("Rysik istnieje"), -1, &ClientRect, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);

    // 'the drawing loop'
        for (int i = 0; i < iloscPunktow; i++)
            {
                punkt.x = lgXokna + ((pdXokna - lgXokna)*(rysik->getSingleData(i,0) - minX)/(maxX - minX));
                punkt.y = pdYokna - ((pdYokna - lgYokna)*(rysik->getSingleData(i,1) - minY)/(maxY - minY));
                if (i > 0) LineTo(ps.hdc,punkt.x,punkt.y);
                MoveToEx(ps.hdc,punkt.x,punkt.y,NULL);
            }

        SelectObject(hdc,hPenOld);
        DeleteObject(hSolidPen);
        DeleteObject(hBluePen);
        delete rysik;

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_SIZE:
        GetClientRect(hWnd,&ClientRect); // update the client area dimensions (and the plot shape with it)
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

#### daneWykres.h

```
#ifndef DANEWYKRES_H_INCLUDED
#define DANEWYKRES_H_INCLUDED

#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class daneWykres {

static const int rozmiar = 3490; // number of data points

private:
    bool flaga; // set to 'true' when constructor is called
    ifstream file;
    string value;
    double wartosc;
    double data[rozmiar][2];

public:
    daneWykres();
    ~daneWykres();
    double strToDouble(string);
    void sczytaj(); // reading method adjusted to the contents of 'file.csv'
    double najmniejsza(int indeksKolumny); // returns minimum value in a dataset
    double najwieksza(int indeksKolumny); // returns maximum value in a dataset
    int getRozmiar();
    // returns an X or Y coordinate of a data point by row and column index, respectively
    double getSingleData(int indeksWiersza, int indeksKolumny);
    bool getFlaga();
};

#endif // DANEWYKRES_H_INCLUDED
```

#### daneWykres.cpp

```
#include "daneWykres.h"

daneWykres::daneWykres()
{
    file.open("file.csv");
    flaga = true;
}

daneWykres::~daneWykres()
{
    file.close();
    flaga = false;
}

double daneWykres::strToDouble(string zapis)
{
    const char* c = zapis.c_str();
    return atof(c);
}

void daneWykres::sczytaj()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < rozmiar)
        {
            getline(file,value,',');
            wartosc = strToDouble(value);
            data[i][0] = wartosc;
            getline(file,value,',');
            wartosc = strToDouble(value);
            data[i][1] = wartosc;
            getline(file,value,'\n');
            i++;
        }
}

double daneWykres::najmniejsza(int indeksKolumny)
{
    double najmniejsza = data[0][indeksKolumny];
    for (int i = 0; i < rozmiar; i++) najmniejsza = ((data[i][indeksKolumny] < najmniejsza) ? data[i][indeksKolumny] : najmniejsza);
    return najmniejsza;
}

double daneWykres::najwieksza(int indeksKolumny)
{
    double najwieksza = data[0][indeksKolumny];
    for (int i = 0; i < rozmiar; i++) najwieksza = ((data[i][indeksKolumny] > najwieksza) ? data[i][indeksKolumny] : najwieksza);
    return najwieksza;
}

int daneWykres::getRozmiar()
{
    return rozmiar;
}

double daneWykres::getSingleData(int indeksWiersza, int indeksKolumny)
{
    return data[indeksWiersza][indeksKolumny];
}

bool daneWykres::getFlaga()
{
    return flaga;
}
```

Also, here's the link to a zip containing 'file.csv', just in case:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QHore2OJpQqaAzgxJEiVJIs0BFiSShFo/view?usp=sharing

Whenever I'm running the build via Code::Blocks (don't mind the title) on a machine with Win XP SP1, I see this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTk4W.jpg

And after resizing or minimizing a few times I see this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8gVj.jpg

I initially thought it was a matter of the object from `daneWykres` class being prematurely destroyed but the 'Rysik istnieje' string displays properly.

I've got hold of "Programming Windows" by C. Petzold recently but I'm still struggling to understand the basic concepts underlaying WinAPI and it shows.

So, the main question is: why are the black line rectangle and 'Rysik istnieje' string being drawn, yet the blue plot lines cease to be drawn at some point?

EDIT:

I've moved the `delete rysik` back to the end of the `WM_PAINT` message. I've separated the declarations and assignments and moved it all into the `WM_PAINT` message (along with allocation to and deallocation from `rysik`). This has seemingly helped limit the memory/resource leak.

I've moved the code for opening and reading the file into global functions. The resulting application seems to run smoother but I don't see any significant changes in the Task Manager compared to the earlier edit.

Here's what I have thus far:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "daneWykres.h"

static TCHAR szWindowClass[] = _T("win32app");

static TCHAR szTitle[] = _T("My Application");

double data[3490][2];

POINT logicalUnitSize;
RECT ClientRect;

HINSTANCE hInst;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

double strToDouble(string zapis)
{
    const char* c = zapis.c_str();
    return atof(c);
}

void sczytaj(ifstream& file, double (&data)[3490][2])
{
    double wartosc;
    string line;
    unsigned int i = 0;
    unsigned int pos, pos2;
    while (getline(file,line))
        {
            pos = 0;
            pos2 = line.find(',',pos);
            wartosc = strToDouble(line.substr(pos,(pos2-pos)));
            data[i][0] = wartosc;
            pos = pos2 + 1;
            pos2 = line.find(',',pos);
            wartosc = strToDouble(line.substr(pos,(pos2-pos)));
            data[i][1] = wartosc;

            i++;
        }
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,
            _T("Call to RegisterClassEx failed!"),
            _T("Win32 Guided Tour"),
            0);

        return 1;
    }

    hInst = hInstance;

    ifstream file;
    file.open("file.csv");
    sczytaj(file,data);
    file.close();

    logicalUnitSize.x = 560;
    logicalUnitSize.y = 560;

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(
        szWindowClass,
        szTitle,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        100, 100,
        logicalUnitSize.x, logicalUnitSize.y,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
    );

    if (!hWnd)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,
            _T("Call to CreateWindow failed!"),
            _T("Win32 Guided Tour"),
            0);

        return 1;
    }

    GetClientRect(hWnd,&ClientRect);

    ShowWindow(hWnd,
        nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        daneWykres* rysik;
        rysik = new daneWykres;
        int iloscPunktow;
        iloscPunktow = rysik->getRozmiar();

        double minX, minY, maxX, maxY;
        minX = rysik->najmniejsza(data, 0);
        minY = rysik->najmniejsza(data, 1);
        maxX = rysik->najwieksza(data, 0);
        maxY = rysik->najwieksza(data, 1);

        int lgXokna, lgYokna, pdXokna, pdYokna;
        lgXokna = 30;
        lgYokna = 30;
        pdXokna = ClientRect.right - lgXokna;
        pdYokna = ClientRect.bottom - lgYokna;

        POINT punkt;
        punkt.x = 0;
        punkt.y = 0;

        HPEN hPen;
        HPEN hSolidPen;
        HPEN hBluePen;
        hSolidPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(0,0,0));
        hBluePen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 2, RGB(0,0,255));
        hPen = (HPEN)SelectObject(hdc, hSolidPen);

        Rectangle(ps.hdc, lgXokna, lgYokna, pdXokna, pdYokna);

        SelectObject(hdc,hPen);
        DeleteObject(hSolidPen);

        hPen = (HPEN)SelectObject(hdc, hBluePen);

        if (rysik) DrawText(ps.hdc, TEXT("Rysik istnieje"), -1, &ClientRect, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);

        for (int i = 0; i < iloscPunktow; i++)
            {
                punkt.x = lgXokna + ((pdXokna - lgXokna)*(data[i][0] - minX)/(maxX - minX));
                punkt.y = pdYokna - ((pdYokna - lgYokna)*(data[i][1] - minY)/(maxY - minY));
                if (i > 0) LineTo(ps.hdc,punkt.x,punkt.y);
                MoveToEx(ps.hdc,punkt.x,punkt.y,NULL);
            }

        SelectObject(hdc,hPen);
        DeleteObject(hBluePen);
        delete rysik;

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_SIZE:
        GetClientRect(hWnd,&ClientRect);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**daneWykres.h**

```
#ifndef DANEWYKRES_H_INCLUDED
#define DANEWYKRES_H_INCLUDED

#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class daneWykres {

static const int rozmiar = 3490;

private:

public:
    daneWykres();
    ~daneWykres();
    double najmniejsza( double (&data)[3490][2], int indeksKolumny);
    double najwieksza( double (&data)[3490][2], int indeksKolumny);
    int getRozmiar();
};

#endif // DANEWYKRES_H_INCLUDED
```

**daneWykres.cpp**

```
#include "daneWykres.h"

daneWykres::daneWykres()
{

}

daneWykres::~daneWykres()
{

}

double daneWykres::najmniejsza( double (&data)[3490][2], int indeksKolumny)
{
    double najmniejsza = data[0][indeksKolumny];
    for (int i = 0; i < rozmiar; i++) najmniejsza = ((data[i][indeksKolumny] < najmniejsza) ? data[i][indeksKolumny] : najmniejsza);
    return najmniejsza;
}

double daneWykres::najwieksza( double (&data)[3490][2], int indeksKolumny)
{
    double najwieksza = data[0][indeksKolumny];
    for (int i = 0; i < rozmiar; i++) najwieksza = ((data[i][indeksKolumny] > najwieksza) ? data[i][indeksKolumny] : najwieksza);
    return najwieksza;
}

int daneWykres::getRozmiar()
{
    return rozmiar;
}
```

Comment: You never check return values of functions. `hPenOld = (HPEN)SelectObject(hdc, hBluePen);` overwrites value stored in `hPenOld` with `hSolidPen`. So cleanup probably fails since pen is still in use.

Comment: Symptoms suggest a resource leak. Checking return values for errors is a good start. I'm sure Petzold does that.

Comment: Why are all calculations and assignments outside `case WM_PAINT`? Good practice for destroying pens/brushed/etc: `DeleteObject( SelectObject(h dc, hPenOld ) );`

Comment: Why do you call `delete rysik;` only while processing WM_PAINT message ? Object `daneWykres` is created with every call of WindowProcedure, but is destroyed only with WM_PAINT message, you have serious memory leak.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsui_team/2013/04/23/debugging-a-gdi-resource-leak/ it looks relevant to my question

Comment: @rafix07 You're right, I was concerned about it. I've moved the `delete rysik` outside the body of the switch, before the end of WindowProcedure. I've also tried to build with one pen only, for simplicity's sake. Should I edit the main.cpp code to reflect the changes or rather paste EDIT: and just show the changes to the WndProc and NOT edit the original code?

Comment: You can edit main.cpp with your last changes.

Comment: hPenOld is not the old pen, it is the hSolidPen pen.  So you are leaking pen objects, the show is over when you leaked 10,000 of them.  Easiest way to diagnose this is with Task Manager, Processes tab.   Add the GDI Object counter.

Comment: @Hans Passant Thanks, I've just used the Task Manager. GDI Object counter reached only 20 objects or so but I'm leaking memory like crazy.

Comment: @i486 Thanks for your valuable suggestion! I've posted the results in the EDIT. However, I can only answer my own question with a brief: "It was a memory leak." It solves my problem in principle but I don't feel confident at all to elaborate on the subject.

Comment: `DeleteObject(SelectObject(hdc,hSolidPen));` selects the wrong pen into the DC. As a result, the `DeleteObject` fails because you are trying to delete a selected object. GDI leak. Also, you don't want to open and reread the file on every paint message. Cache the results.